# Quickest way to duplicate a MySQL Record

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

Simple question, i have a query with some WHERE and i need to duplicate it with a change to 1 field to a different value? There is a unique increment ID field as well which I cannot duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work. This will give you access to the row that you want to duplicate, and you just select the values to insert for the new row, replacing one of them.

```
INSERT tblData
( -- Lets pretend Column1 is your key
   Column2
   , Column3
)
SELECT
   Column2
   , Column3 + 5 /*Replace this with whatever value is you want*/
FROM tblData
WHERE Column1 = @Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table(field1,field2)
SELECT field1*x, field2 /*Replace accordingly*/
FROM table
WHERE key = @Id
```